# Windows 10 goes infinite black screen after I don't use computer some time

Tags: windows-10

When I leave my computer, after some time, my screen goes black and I can't do anything, mouse and keyboard seems to be working, but I can't get computer back to normal, only restart or shutdown works.

I tried replugging monitor, turning off scheduled sleep, but nothing works. Interesting thing is, that this problem doesn't appear on Ubuntu.

P.S. There's just black screen, cursor is not shown, and, if that matters, I have 2 monitors and my BIOS is up-to-date.

Comment: Check in Windows Settings, Power and Sleep and in Windows Advanced Power Options if you have both Suspend and Hibernate set to run. The machine may be Hibernating and if that is the case, pressing the power button once should bring it back.

Comment: I tried pressing power button, but that doesn't work

Comment: Did you try disabling Hibernate for sure, and then make sure Suspend settings are correct (not using power button)

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure computer doesn't hibernate and this time, when I left my computer and came back, it was working fine, although, I haven't changed settings from last time when bug appeared.

Comment: As it turned out today, this bug haven't gone yet